# Trouble logging out from a Grails application using Spring Security (CAS)

Tags: grails, spring-security, cas

I have a Grails application with Spring Security implemented (CAS). However, after I hit the logout button, I am not logged out. I have the `LogoutController`, with following code:

```
class LogoutController {
    def index = {
        println "IN LOGOUT CONTROLLER TRYING TO LOGOUT"
       redirect uri: SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig.logout.filterProcessesUrl // '/j_spring_security_logout'
    }

    def accessDenied = {

    }
}
```

And in my `Config.groovy` file, I have:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.logout.afterLogoutUrl = 'https://login.test.com/cas/logout'
```

The code for my GSP page is

```
<g:link controller='Logout'>Logout</g:link>
```

However, when I click the logout button I get redirected, but not fully logged out. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post the code (presumably GSP) behind the “logout” button?

Comment: I was able to log out without any trouble once I removed the `afterLogoutUrl` from `Config.groovy`. Can you perhaps try that?

Comment: Nope it did not work for me.Did you use the same controller code and view code as mine?

Comment: I’m using the Spring Security Core plugin and ran its `s2-quickstart` script. But I’m using your “Logout” GSP code and I copied your `LogoutController` from the post over the generated one. The generated one starts with an import of `SpringSecurityUtils`; **I left that.** Is that in yours?

Comment: Yep I have that in mine

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried call `session.invalidate()` direct in the controller index method?

```
class LogoutController {
    def index = {
        println "IN LOGOUT CONTROLLER TRYING TO LOGOUT"
        session.invalidate()
        redirect uri: SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig.logout.filterProcessesUrl
    }
}
```

Cheers

Comment: Needed this to. Without `session.invalidate` in my gsp `<sec:ifLoggedIn>` would be seen as still logged in.

Answer (score 0):

```
<g:link controller='Logout'>Logout</g:link>

def index = {

    logoutProcessService.process(params)
    redirect uri: SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig.logout.filterProcessesUr
}
```

Comment: Please, edit your answer and add some explanation to your code.